# pointer to many structures in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I can have many sensors. Each sensor has an address, current and pressure. Due to the fact I don't know how many sensors there could be, I thought of creating a pointer to structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sensor {
  unsigned long long int           address;
  float                            current;
  unsigned char                    pressure_units;
};

static struct sensor *sensors;

struct sensor *createSensor(unsigned long long int address, float current, unsigned char pressure_units)
{
  struct sensor *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct sensor));
  // (*temp).address
  temp->address = address;
  temp->current = current;
  temp->pressure_units = pressure_units;
  return temp;
}

void checkSerialHart(int sensorId)
{
    sensors = createSensor(10000*sensorId,sensorId+3.0,sensorId);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0,j=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        // test case where sensor n doesn't respond
        if(i != 1)
        {
            checkSerialHart(j);
            ++j;
            ++sensors;
        }
    }
    printf("address: %llu current: %f pressure: %c\n", sensors[0].address, sensors[0].current, sensors[0].pressure_units);
    printf("address: %llu current: %f pressure: %c\n", sensors[1].address, sensors[1].current, sensors[1].pressure_units);
}
```

I am having trouble keeping a pointer to structs where I can move through the pointer to get values of different sensors. The above prints this:

```
address: 580340276002816 current: 0.000000 pressure: 
address: 0 current: 0.000000 pressure:
```

But I expected this:

```
address:0,current:3.000000,pressure_units:0
address:20000,current:5.000000,pressure_units:2
```

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkSerialHart()` will overwrite `sensors` every time you call it.

Here is one way (not the best) to achieve your goal:

```
static struct sensor **sensors;
static int sensors_count = 0;

...

void checkSerialHart(int sensorId)
{
    sensors = realloc(sensors, (sensors_count+1)*sizeof(*sensors));
    if (sensors == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    sensors[sensors_count] = createSensor(10000*sensorId,sensorId+3.0,sensorId);
    sensors_count++;
}

...

for(i=0,j=0;i<3;i++)
{
    // test case where sensor n doesn't respond
    if(i != 1)
    {
        checkSerialHart(j);
        ++j;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < sensors_count; i++)
    printf("address: %llu current: %f pressure: %c\n",
        sensors[i]->address, sensors[i]->current, sensors[i]->pressure_units);
```

Comment: It overwrites even though I use pointer arithmetic? ++sensors;

Comment: You say "not the best". Do you mean some kind of node tree would be better?

Comment: @JohnMerlino The addresses returned by `createSensor()` are not contiguous, therefore `++sensors;` does not make sens in this case.

Comment: @JohnMerlino The best or fittest solution depends on your specific situation. For example, if you know how many sensors you will have, allocated (dynamically or statically) an array of pointers to `struct sensor` would be preferred.

Comment: Strangely this gives an error like this: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct sensor’ from type ‘struct sensor *’

Comment: @JohnMerlino The type of `sensors` should be `struct sensor **`. Answer updated.

Comment: cool, one other thing to note is that since its now a pointer to a pointer, the last line needs to be (*sensors[i]).address, (*sensors[i]).current, (*sensors[i]).pressure_units rather than sensors[i]->address, sensors[i]->current, sensors[i]->pressure_units

Comment: @JohnMerlino Those are different syntax for the same thing.

Comment: I ended up removing dynamic memory allocation and used array instead and I get same results but without memory leaks. Using pointers to pointers and so forth it was hard to keep track of memory, especially since this was running in a loop.

Comment: @JohnMerlino Yeah, memory management in C is difficult, and it is hard to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your following line is causing the problem:

```
++sensors;
```

"sensors" is the global static variable which should be store the base pointer of your array. But inside your for loop, it gets incremented and starts pointing to next(some memory). Hence while printing, it does starts pointing to base address which you wanted to achieve from this program.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your

```
static struct sensor *sensors;
```

points to a single sensor.  When you increment it, you no longer point at a valid sensor, causing undefined behaviour when you later deference.

You have to choose between one of two fundamentally different designs:

1. An array of sensors
2. An array of pointers to sensor

(As I write, the other solution mixes up these two options, it won't work as posted).

If you go with option (2) then the only modification you need to make is:

```
static struct sensor *sensors[MAX_SENSORS];
static size_t num_sensors = 0;
```

Then you can do `sensors[num_sensors++] = createSensor(....`

You should avoid doing `++sensors`, and instead either use an index or another pointer if you want to iterate over the sensors.  You could also dynamically allocate `sensors` instead of having a fixed maximum.

For option (1) you would need to re-design the `createSensor` function.  It can no longer return a pointer to a new Sensor, nor `malloc` memory for a single sensor.  Instead, you have to increase the size of your dynamically-allocated sensor array, and then create the new sensor in the space you just allocated.

In either case I would suggest having separate functions for "growing" your allocated storage, than for initializing a new sensor. That will help keep your code clear and easy to maintain.